# power BI( how can I show 0.5 days in my report?)

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I want to use Dax to calculate someone was work at half day but I dun know how to complete the Dax....try a lot of Dax but still dose not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te1Vm.png)

import csv

total_working_days = {}

with open('2024_1 (1).csv', 'r') as file:
reader = csv.DictReader(file)

```
for row in reader:
    staff_name = row['StaffName']
    work_hours = row['WorkHour']
    remark = row['Remark']
    
    if work_hours != '0 - 0':
        if staff_name in total_working_days:
            total_working_days[staff_name] += 1
        else:
            total_working_days[staff_name] = 1
    elif staff_name == 'Kelvin' and remark == 'SL (PM)':
        if staff_name in total_working_days:
            total_working_days[staff_name] += 0.5
        else:
            total_working_days[staff_name] = 0.5
```

print(total_working_days)

WorkingDay =
IF(
COUNTX(
FILTER(
Table1,
OR(
OR(
Table1[StaffName] = "Kelvin",
Table1[StaffName] = "Hin"
),
Table1[StaffName] = "Kilson"
) && Table1[WorkHour] = "SL(PM)"
)
) >= 1,
0.5,
IF(
COUNTX(
FILTER(
Table1,
OR(
OR(
Table1[StaffName] = "Wency",
Table1[StaffName] = "Helen"
),
Table1[StaffName] = "DifferentName"
) && Table1[WorkHour] = "SL(PM)"
)
) >= 1,
0.5,
IF(
COUNTX(
FILTER(
Table1,
OR(
OR(
Table1[StaffName] = "Kelvin",
Table1[StaffName] = "Hin"
),
Table1[StaffName] = "Kilson"
) && Table1[WorkHour] <> "OFF" && Table1[WorkHour] <> "AL"
)
) >= 1,
1,
IF(
COUNTX(
FILTER(
Table1,
OR(
OR(
Table1[StaffName] = "Wency",
Table1[StaffName] = "Helen"
),
Table1[StaffName] = "DifferentName"
) && Table1[WorkHour] <> "OFF" && Table1[WorkHour] <> "AL"
)
) >= 1,
1,
0
)
)
)
)